Since $\cos (30^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, why isn't $\cos(180^\circ)=6 \cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$?
If I have the value of ($\theta$) [ex: $28.7 \, \text{degrees}$] and I need to find the value of $\cos[3(\theta)]$, should I simply substitute the value of $\theta$ in $\cos[3(\theta)]$, i.e. $\cos(3 \times 28.7)$ or should I use some other formula or identity?
If the answer is "YES", then consider this:
$\cos (30^\circ)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, so $\cos(180^\circ) =\cos(6 \times 30^\circ)$ should be equal to $6 \times \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
Then why is $\cos (180^\circ)=-1$?

If "YES".  You seem to use $\cos(6\theta) = 6\cos(\theta)$, which is not correct.

@GEdgar is right. In fact$$\cos6\theta=32\cos^6\theta-48\cos^4\theta+18\cos^2\theta-1.$$

Your two previous questions already have the same response. Remember - the trig functions are not linear, and you must follow the order of operations!

Your first thought is correct. With $\cos(6\theta)$, you first multiply $\theta$ by $6$, then find the cosine of that.

another problem is that cosine of an angle is never above $1$  or below $-1,$   while your suggested $3 \sqrt 3 = \sqrt {27} $ is larger than $5$  and can't be the cosine of anything

Sine and Cosine are not linear maps.
A Linear map $f$ has these properties:
$$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
and the one which you believe cosine has
$$f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$$
Since cosine is not linear, it is not true in general that $\cos(\alpha x) = \alpha \cos(x)$
Another function that you may know that is not a linear map is $x^2$ for example, it is not true in general that $6x^2$ is the same as $(6x)^2$. Except for $x=0$, $6x^2 \neq 36x^2$
We can see why cosine is not a linear map from its definition using the taylor series ($x$ is in radians):
$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} ...$$
Since it has at least one non-linear term, it is not a linear map.
